# Can i have a table that can appear between two rows of another table in html?

Tags: html, css

I have to display a table between two rows of another table without affecting the original table?Is this possible using HTML or CSS?

Comment: Why not adding another row in the middle of the main table. and put a table inside that new added row.

Comment: semantically NO after "#element row: tr" cannot be used "#element: table" - however visually YES you can wrap-encapsulate "#element: table" into "#element row: td" --- "table > tr > td colspan:{{number}} > table"

Answer (score 2):

This might help you:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style>
  table, th, td {
      border: 1px solid black;
      border-collapse: collapse;
  }
  th, td {
      padding: 5px;
  }
</style>
</head>
<body>

<table>
<tr>
    <td>This cell contains a list
      <ul>
        <li>apples</li>
        <li>bananas</li>
        <li>pineapples</li>
      </ul>
    </td>
    <td>HELLO</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td colspan='2'>This cell contains a table:
      <table>
        <tr>
          <td>A</td>
          <td>B</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>C</td>
          <td>D</td>
        </tr>
      </table>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>This cell contains a list
      <ul>
        <li>apples</li>
        <li>bananas</li>
        <li>pineapples</li>
      </ul>
    </td>
    <td>HELLO</td>
  </tr>
</table>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Depending on what you are trying to do exactly, you could just add another row with a td and colspan of the colums you want and then put the table in it.

Good luck

```css
table {
  border-collapse: collapse;
  border: 1px solid black;
}

td {
  width: 100px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  padding: 5px;
}

#table1 {
  background: crimson;
}

#table2 {
  background: green;
}
```

```html
<table id="table1">
  <tr>
    <td>1</td>
    <td>2</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td colspan=2>
  <table id="table2">
        <tr>
          <td>1</td>
          <td>2</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>1</td>
          <td>2</td>
        </tr>
      </table>
    </td>
  </tr>    
  <tr>
    <td>1</td>
    <td>2</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can easily use css flexbox to achieve table structure and beyond in any way you like. 
Refer to my [codepen](https://codepen.io/anchal20/pen/vWBjJN) link for the demo

```
<div id="table1" class="table">
  <div id="row1" class="row">
    <div class="column outer-col">table1 row 1 col1</div>
    <div class="column outer-col">table1 row 1 col2</div>
  </div>
  <div id="table2" class="table">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="column inner-col">table2 row 1 col1</div>
      <div class="column inner-col">table2 row 1 col2</div>
      <div class="column inner-col">table2 row 1 col3</div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="column inner-col">table2 row 2 col1</div>
      <div class="column inner-col">table2 row 2 col2</div>
      <div class="column inner-col">table2 row 2 col3</div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div id="row2" class="row">
    <div class="column outer-col">table1 row 2 col1</div>
    <div class="column outer-col">table1 row 2 col2</div>
  </div>
</div>

.table {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

#table1 {
  border: 1px solid;
}
.row {
  border: 1px solid;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
}
.column {
  height: 100%;
  border-left: 1px solid;
  width: 100%;
}
.inner-col {
  background-color: green;
}
.outer-col {
  background-color: yellow;
}
```